# Как привязать домен к ip адресу в ubuntu (DNS сервер)?

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, маршрутизация, dns

Есть домен mydomen.ru.

Есть сервер со статичным внешним ip адресом (42.12.12.44) на ubuntu.

Каким образом можно привязать этот домен к этому ip адресу?
Чтобы например там(в DNS сервере) можно было прописывать соответствия для локальных ip адресов местной локальной сети?

site.mydomen.ru 192.168.1.50

То есть обращаясь вне(или внутри) сети к site.mydomen.ru,
в конечном итоге запрос бы приходил на локальный компьютер 192.168.1.50:80

Comment: проброска на внутренние машины по именам доменов работать не может в принципе. потому что проброска работает на уровне ip, а там нет никаких имен. только ip-адреса и порты. Если это конкретно web, то на внешней машине ставится web-proxy (обычно nginx в этом режиме) и в нем уже все описывается. Что касается DNS то в ней для всех нужных поддоменов ставится один и тот же адрес - ваш внешний. Внутри сети при желании поднимается локальная dns зона с таким же именем, в которой пишутся внутренние адреса (но разумеется это исключительно для удобства работы внутри)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках домена вы должны прописать DNS записи типа А. Host .mydomen.ru - 42.12.12.44. Тогда ваш домен будет связан с IP адресом.

Comment: А где можно прописать соответствия поддемонов локальным компьютерам?

Comment: Это делается уже на локальном сервере

Comment: это понятно, но вопрос в чем именно это прописать. Я когда то это делал в windows там был встроенный DNS сервер, а в ubuntu как? Просто прописать в /etc/hosts записи во всех узлах?

Comment: @manking В Linux в 90% случаев используется DNS-сервер bind. Ему пишутся его собственные конфигурационные файлы и файлы с описаниями зон. В большинстве дистрибутивов все его конфиги находятся в /etc/bind.

Comment: Когда A запись прописал, то по ip адресу внешнему сайт отображается, а по доменному имени выскакивает ошибка "404 Not Found
nginx". 
При этом в сервисе 2ip.ru по этому доменному имени возвращается мой внешний ip адрес.
Как понять куда вообще идёт запрос и от кого получен ответ?

Comment: Смотрите логи и настройки сервера, тут экстрасенсов нет. IP к домену вы привязали, а дальше надо настраивать сервер.