# Настройка сервера-сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

У меня есть `домен` и `IP` для моего сайта.

Но как далше привязать IP к моему сайту?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как привязать домен к ip адресу в ubuntu (DNS сервер)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944113/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%ba-ip-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83-%d0%b2-ubuntu-dns-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80)

Answer (score 1):

Там где, покупали домен, обычно есть панель управления - поищите настройки ns
(nameserver):
если у Вас хостинг - спросите точные адреса ns серверов в техподдержке и внесите их в настройки домена.
Процедура смены DNS у разных провайдеров по сути одна и та же. Например, управление DNS может находиться в разделах «Управление DNS», «Настройка домена», «Настройка услуг» и т.п.
В DNS укажите настройки следующим образом: (тут пример для делегирования в Яндекс)

```
dns1.yandex.net. 
dns2.yandex.net.
```

Значения указывайте вместе с точками (у некоторых хостеров без точек). Сохраните изменения.

> **DNS-сервер** (Name-сервер, nameserver, NS) — *сервер, преобразующий доменные имена, с которыми работают пользователи, в понятные
> компьютерам IP-адреса или в обратном направлении. Обычно не делают
> разницы между понятиями NS и DNS-серверов.*

Если у Вас vps, vds сервер, то смотрите инструкции как поднять dns сервер самому или воспользоваться сторонним dns сервером - обычно у кого арендуете сервер есть такая услуга.

если нет, то я, например, пользуюсь, услугами Яндекс.Коннект - бесплатно + почта на серверах Яндекса. Но есть и другие компании предоставляющие свои услуги как "Управление DNS домена"
надо добавить  записи типа "А"  с хостами "www" и "@", значение - Ваш IP. TLL 21600

Начать советую с этой страницы - https://yandex.ru/support/business/domains.html